# Load html file with it folder

Tags: c#, .net

My current code load .swf, how can I change current code to load .html file with it folder. Full function as below:

```
    List<SqlParameter> _lstParam = new List<SqlParameter>();
    SqlFileStream _sfsFile = null;

             string _strQuery = @"EXECUTE AS LOGIN='" + SystemInfo.ImpersonateAccount + "';" +
            "SELECT Content.PathName() AS Path, File_Name " +
            "FROM M_OnlineQuiz Q INNER JOIN M_OnlineQuizRev QR ON Q.M_OnlineQuiz_ID = QR.M_OnlineQuiz_ID " +
            " WHERE  Q.M_OnlineQuiz_ID =@pM_OnlineQuiz_ID AND QR.IsActive = 1; " +
            "REVERT; ";
        _lstParam.Add(new SqlParameter("@pM_OnlineQuiz_ID", M_OnlineQuiz_ID));
        DataTable _dtTemp = this._daAdapter.Fill(_strQuery, _lstParam.ToArray());
        if (_dtTemp.Rows.Count <= 0)
            return;

        _strQuery = @"EXECUTE AS LOGIN='" + SystemInfo.ImpersonateAccount + "';" +
            "SELECT GET_FILESTREAM_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT(); " +
            "REVERT; ";
        byte[] objContext = (byte[])this._daAdapter.ExecuteScalar(_strQuery, null);

        _sfsFile = new SqlFileStream(_dtTemp.Rows[0]["Path"].ToString(),
            objContext, FileAccess.Read);
        context.Response.BufferOutput = false;
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/x-shockwave-flash";
        context.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "private,must-revalidate,post-check=1,pre-check=2,no-cache");
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", _sfsFile.Length.ToString());
        Global.Copy(_sfsFile, context.Response.OutputStream);
```

Comment: It is unclear of what you asking. What is `SqlFileStream`? What is `_dtTemp`? What is `objContext`? What is `context`? What is `Global`? And what do you mean by _"html file folder"_?

Comment: I change to original function

Comment: Ok, now it is a bit more clear, however, what is _"html file folder"_?

Comment: @vasily.sib a html file with it folder that consist of css folder, javascript folder and image folder

Comment: Oh, I see. You mean a folder, that is created when you save html page with your browser. There is no such thing as "html file folder" and it is a browser, who create this folder, save there html page assets and change every link on this page.